# Border-image-slice effect on Progress Bar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I have a simple bootstrap progress bar, which I would like to use a sliced effect on, similar to the `border-image-slice` CSS style. Obviously, I can't use this CSS because the progress bar doesn't use a border.

```
<div class="progress progress-xs" style="width:60%; background-color:#343F54;">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%; background-color:#2A6EBB;">
    <span class="sr-only">60%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get a small 5px or so, transparent gap every 10% of the progress bar, is this possible? Here is an example:

[image]

As requested, I have an example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgtm5qx2/)

Comment: Can you please provide your progress bar demo in snippet or fiddle?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/cgtm5qx2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider a linear-gradeint as background that you can easily adjust to create the gap you want:

```css
.progress-bar,.progress{
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#fff 5%,transparent 0) 0 0/ 100px 100% ;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="progress progress-xs" style="background-color:#343F54;">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%; background-color:#2A6EBB; border-color:#343F54; border-width:5px;">
                  <span class="sr-only">60%</span>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Yes, that works absolutely perfectly for my requirements and is a very simple solution - Thanks for the help!